# Retrieve object stored in a generic class from another class

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn generic classes and so far its going pretty well. I have one problem however, might be that I'm blind, but I have issues accessing a object from another non-generic class

Say this is my generic class:

```
public class Fridge<T> {

private T beer;

// Forgot to add (T beer) thanks for pointing that out
public void storeBeer(T beer) {
this.beer = beer;
}
public T getBeer() {
  return beer;
}
```

There is the class Beer:

```
public class Beer {

private String brand;
private int amountLeft;

Beer(String brand, int amountLeft) {
  this.brand = brand;
  this.amountLeft = amountLeft;
  } 
}
```

The test class:

```
public class Test {

Fridge<Beer> myFridge = new Fridge<Beer>();
Beer b1 = new Beer("Samuel Adams", 6);
// Another line I forgot to add, thanks for pointing out
myFridge.storeBeer(b1);
}
```

Now lets say I have another class Drink:

```
public class Drink {

public Beer drinkBeer(Fridge f) {
  //Here I miss code
  return null;
  }
}
```

I am trying to understand how to access the object b1 from the class Drink, Say I want to know what beer I have in the fridge and also how many beers there are left. I have been hammering away and can't solve this bit, anyone who could help me in the right direction?

Comment: In `Drink` you rmethod should be `Beer drinkBeer(Fridge<Beer> f)` then you would not have problems.

Comment: 1) `storeBeer` needs to take a `T beer` parameter. 2) In `Test`, you need to call `storeBeer(b1)`. 3) In `drinkBeer`, you need to call `f.getBeer()`.

Comment: Thanks guys, no more java.lang.NullPointerException when I compile, I really apprecite the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the `T` (`Beer`) object like this:

```
public Beer drinkBeer(Fridge f) {
  return f.<Beer>getBeer();
}
```

Comment: Actually, in my opinion, the right way is to declared `Fridge` as generic reference and nto as raw type reference as done here and in the original example (e.g. `Fridge<Beer>`).

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to make your method argument generic, so something like:

you can get the T (Beer) object like this:

```
public T drinkBeverage(Fridge<T> f) {
  return f.getBeverage();
}
```

The advantage here is that now you can drink anything, including beer 😃